# is it safe to keep confidential database table in appcache

Tags: html, web-applications, html5-appcache, offlineapps

I'm going to create a Webapp. As I want to allow the user to login on offline mode. Is it safe to keep confidential tables in Appcache of the browser for offline access?

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not save! Never trust the data from/on your client! 
If someone gets access to the browser, the cache and your code can be seen/analysed/chanced.

What you can do:

- Store the access-data hash and salted, so it is more expensive to get
  it. But only the login of the one, who is just logged in.
- If the application goes offline, reduce the data on the client, as much as
  possible.
- Confidentials shouldn't be at the client longer than
  needed!
- When information is sent back to server after going online
  again, tell the user, what will happen/what happend and check the
  login on the server! Sometimes this is quite annoying for the user,
  but saver.